# Change node edit form template for Drupal 6

Tags: theming, nodes, forms, 6

I have tried this in different ways but nothing seem to work!
I would like to be able to apply a different theme for different node types edit form.
thanks

Comment: This StackOverflow Q&A may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538600/how-can-i-theme-the-template-for-edit-or-add-a-node-for-a-specific-content-type

Comment: try to drop cache

Comment: Thank you but that is for changing the entire page, I just need to change the form layout itself, I have tried the other methods on that page too, non of them worked on Drupal 6